# Show popup immediately on site load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one advertising popup that shows advertisements. However I've been recommended this of code from [Create a one-time popup using jQuery](http://www.veign.com/blog/2008/05/22/create-a-one-time-popup-using-jquery/). The popup working fine and also disabled while cookies set. But this popup will not appear immediately on my websites first page load. After when I navigate to another page it will appear. I just want it to open when first site loads.

Here is my code:

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage"%>
<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    Namespace="System.Web.UI" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="ALL,INDEX,FOLLOW"/>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/slide.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/thickbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/coop/cse/brand?form=cse-search-box&;lang=en"></script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<div id="loading" style="position:absolute; width:100%; text-align:center; top:300px;"><img src="images/loading.gif" alt=""/></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ld = (document.all);
    var ns4 = document.layers;
    var ns6 = document.getElementById && !document.all;
    var ie4 = document.all;
    if (ns4)
        ld = document.loading;
    else if (ns6)
        ld = document.getElementById("loading").style;
    else if (ie4)
        ld = document.all.loading.style;
    function init() {
        if (ns4) { ld.visibility = "hidden"; }
        else if (ns6 || ie4) ld.display = "none";
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   if ($.cookie('20080521') != '1') {
    tb_show("<strong>Seminar on Total Investment!</strong>", "#TB_inline?height=190&width=275&inlineId=mypopup","");
    $.cookie('20080521', '1', { expires: 20 }); }
   });
</script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div id="mypopup" style="display:none"><p id="msg">Seminar on Total Investment By Mr.Samir Shah. Contact: 9727152508</p></div>
```

Comment: Wow. Do you really need it to work on Netscape and IE 4?

Comment: can you make a  demo on http://jsfiddle.net for the popup you require on page load?

Comment: i can't make it on jsfiddle.net it's have too many file need to include like jquery.min.,cookies.ja,and like to thickbox.js

Comment: We don't need the *entire* page. Make a fiddle of only the popup part.

Comment: use window.onload=popUp;, where popUp is u r function name .

Comment: $(window).load( function(){ with this method no effect to this scenario...working like $(document).ready(function(){ method...